# C language. Can't understand the output of the pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

I have the following piece of code.

```
    int a = 10, b = 20;
    int *x, *y, *z;
    int **pp;
    int arr[3] = { 5, 13, 29 };
    x = &b;
    pp = &y;
    y = arr + 1;
    *y = a;
    z = y;
    **pp = 999;
    y++;

    printf("%i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i", a, b, *x, *y, *z, **pp, arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
```

I expected the output would be `10 20 20 29 10 999 5 999 29`, however, the correct output appeared to be `10 20 20 29 999 29 5 999 29`. The differences are in `*z` and `**pp`. I can't understand why so, even though I tried to draw diagrams and analyze the result step by step. Why `*z` and `**pp` are 999 and 29, respectively, not 10 and 999? Thank you.

Comment: `pp = &y` means that `pp` points to the pointer `y`. Which means that `*p` is the same as `y`, and `**pp` is the same as `*y`. So in both statements that use `**pp`, you can change `**pp` to `*y` and get the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After this statement

```
y = arr + 1;
```

the pointer `y` points to the second element of the array `arr`,

So the second element is set to `10` after the next statement

```
*y = a;
```

And we have the following content of the array `arr`

```
{ 5, 10, 29 }
```

The pointer z also points to this second element

```
 z = y;
```

However the second element was rewritten

```
 **pp = 999;
```

because the dereferenced pointer `pp` always yields the pointer `y`. The content of the array now is

```
{ 5, 999, 29 }
```

and the pointer `y` was incremented and after this statement

```
y++;
```

points to the third element of the array. Pay attention to that the pointer `pp` still points to the pointer `y` that stores now the address of the third element of the array.

The variables `a` and `b` were not changed> so the call of `printf` outputs

```
10 20
```

the pointer `x` points to the variable `b` so we have

```
10 20 20
```

The pointer `y` points to the third element of the array. So

```
10 20 20 29
```

The pointer `z` points to the second element of the array because it has the value of the pointer `y` before its increment.

```
10 20 20 29 999
```

The pointer `pp` points to the pointer `y` and as a result the expression `**pp` yields the same value as the expression `*y`

```
10 20 20 29 999 29
```

And these expressions `arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]` sequentially provide values of the array

```
10 20 20 29 999 29 5 999 29
```